# How can i make java collection classes synchronised, without using Collections Class methods?

Tags: java, multithreading, arraylist, synchronization

How can i make an collection classes synchronised, without using Collections Class methods? is there any alternative class? or can i override method of ArrayList Class and then make it synchronise?

Comment: Why can't you use the `Collections` class methods? They sound like the best solution for your issue...

Comment: @SocraticPhoenix Consider a situation, where i want to make my own class synchronized for a particular object not for all the object. how can i implement that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To synchronize any object, you can use an invocation handler that handles synchronization and create a proxy on the object you want to synchronize. For example:

```
public static class Synchronizer implements InvocationHandler{

    private final Object objectToSync;

    public Synchronizer(Object objectToSync){
        this.objectToSync = objectToSync;
    }

    @Override
    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        synchronized (objectToSync){
            return method.invoke(objectToSync, args);
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String ... args) {

    List<Integer> originalList = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Integer> syncList = (List<Integer>) Proxy.newProxyInstance(Synchronizer.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[]{List.class}, new Synchronizer(originalList));

}
```